# Why am I not recieving facebook graph entity_id value from http get request?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, httpresponse, http-get

if I do a simple HTTP GET request with e.g. POSTMAN then in the response there's an element called 'entity_id'.

e.g. https://www.facebook.com/yourFacebookName

If however, I do the request from a simple C# app then the following code doesnt return the 'entity_id' element in the response and I cant figure out why?

Code from app:

```
string html = string.Empty;
string url = string.Format("https://www.facebook.com/{0}", "yourFBName");

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

if (html.Contains("entity_id"))
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

Anyone know why its dropping the 'entity_id' element, but returning it when hitting that url from POSTMAN etc?

Comment: what i'm trying to do is get the entity_id to retrieve the users profile pic.  See here: https://graph.facebook.com/836145057/picture    where 836145057 = entity_id

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed. Use the API